# Storing data to sqlite

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

```
MainData helper = new MainData(this);name
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();        

String uid = MessageRecieverId;
    int userData = 0;
    Cursor data2 = helper.getUserData();
    while (data2.moveToNext()) {
        userData = data2.getInt(data2.getColumnIndex(KEY_MESSAGES_SENT));
    }
    ContentValues contentValues2 = new ContentValues();
    contentValues2.put(KEY_ID, uid);
    contentValues2.put(KEY_MESSAGES_SENT, userData+1);
    long returnVariable2 = db.update(TABLE_USER_DATA, contentValues2,null,null);
    if (returnVariable2 == -1) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Nope", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //-1 means there was an error updating the values
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"uf", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

userData+1 should execute only for what row where KEY_ID = uid but its changing all the rows values to +1 instead of only that... MessageRecieverId is different but the data changing it to all rows... can anyone help me solve this?

Helper

```
    String userQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_USER_DATA + "(" + KEY_ID + " TEXT, " + KEY_NAME
            + " TEXT, " + KEY_MESSAGES_SENT + " INTEGER, " + KEY_MESSAGES_RECIEVED + " INTEGER, "
            + KEY_MESSAGES + " INTEGER, " + KEY_TIME_SPENT + " TEXT)";
```

Method

```
    public Cursor getUserData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USER_DATA;
    return db.rawQuery(query, null);
}
```

I added the whereclause after looking to the answers and getting an error saying no such column exists

Adding default data

```
public void Start(){
    MainData helper = new MainData(this); //Change the name to your Helper Class name
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_ID, MessageRecieverId);
    contentValues.put(KEY_NAME, MessageRecieverName);
    contentValues.put(KEY_MESSAGES_SENT, 0);
    contentValues.put(KEY_MESSAGES_RECIEVED, 0);
    contentValues.put(KEY_MESSAGES, 0);
    contentValues.put(KEY_TIME_SPENT, "");

    long returnVariable = db.insert(TABLE_USER_DATA,null,contentValues);
    if (returnVariable == -1) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Nope", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //-1 means there was an error updating the values
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(MessageRecieverId, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("Data", true); //save that the user enters username
        editor.apply();
    }

}
```

After adding data like this i increment it by one like mentioned above but error shows

```
 Process: com.appmaster.akash.messageplus, PID: 24433
                                                                             android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: eR3C1LXJhzaK3fPzCpcuTuz9jZB3 (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE UserData SET MessagesSent=? WHERE RecieversID =eR3C1LXJhzaK3fPzCpcuTuz9jZB3
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1577)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1525)
                                                                                 at com.appmaster.akash.messageplus.Chat.mMessagesSent(Chat.java:913)
                                                                                 at com.appmaster.akash.messageplus.Chat.sendMessage(Chat.java:704)
                                                                                 at com.appmaster.akash.messageplus.Chat.access$900(Chat.java:75)
                                                                                 at com.appmaster.akash.messageplus.Chat$5.onClick(Chat.java:441)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: there is no update condition given isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE will update every row unless you specify which rows to update.

As such `long returnVariable2 = db.update(TABLE_USER_DATA, contentValues2,null,null);`,

as the selection (3rd parameter) is **null** will update every row.

Selection is a WHERE clause (less the WHERE keyword); the 4th parameter can be used to pass arguments into the WHERE clause replacing **?**'s on a one by one basis.

- passing arguments this way has the advantage that they will be properly enclosed/handled and
- offers protection against SQL injection.

E.g. you most likely want something along the lines of :-

```
//contentValues2.put(KEY_ID, uid); //<<<<<<<<<< YOU PROBABLY DO NOT WANT TO CHANGE THE ID, so commented out
contentValues2.put(KEY_MESSAGES_SENT, userData+1);
String whereclause = KEY_ID + "=?";
String[] whereargs = new String[]{uid};
long returnVariable2 = db.update(TABLE_USER_DATA, contentValues2,whereclause,whereargs);
```

Note that update returns an int not a long and that it will never be -1 as it's the number of rows that have been updated so 0 or greater. So you need to check for 0 not -1 for the Toast

Comment: @NikkiZepher Ooops misy-typed the whereargs line it should be `String[] whereargs = new String[]{uid};` . i.e. curly braces after the square brackets.

Comment: Because the value being inside the square brackets is the number of elements in the array, so as there was an element it grabbed the value *eR3C1LXJhzaK3fPzCpcuTuz9jZB3*, which didn't get enclosed in quotes an thus as it was a string not a number SQL thinks it's a column name.

Comment: There was a red line under ur code so i tried In.parse Int like this but got an error
        String[] whereargs = new String[Integer.parseInt(uid)];

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.appmaster.akash.messageplus, PID: 31033
                                                                                 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "eR3C1LXJhzaK3fPzCpcuTuz9jZB3"
                                                                                     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
                                                                                     at

Comment: Integer.parseint(???) takes a sting and converts it to an integer what number do you reckon eR3C1LXJhzaK3fPzCpcuTuz9jZB3 is? I'd suggest copying the snippet again (tested it and syntactically it's correct)

Answer (score 1):

You are specifically setting your `where` clause and `where args` parameter in the `db.update` call to `null`.  That's why the command is updating all rows, because there is no `where` clause.

You need to change the last two parameters in this line:

```
long returnVariable2 = db.update(TABLE_USER_DATA, contentValues2,null,null);
```

Here's the details from the official docs:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])

Answer (score 0):

```
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("isSynced", 1);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, "id =" + recID, null);
```

update the code with where condition. Hope it will works

Comment: exception is no such column

Comment: Yeah i got that... but why